# how to fix "The import org.junit.jupiter"?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit3, junit-jupiter

I'm working on MMU project and I don't know how to fix this error on `@Test` annotation.

[image]

How I can fix it? I have added `JUnit` library but that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit Jupiter is part of JUnit 5. Chances are you've added an older version of JUnit (especially judging by the [junit3](/questions/tagged/junit3) tag in your question).

You need to add JUnit's Jupiter's engine and api jars:

- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.2.0
- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.2.0