# java junit test fails to compile in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

For my first attempt to work with both junit and eclipse, I have created a small test class, which resides in the src directory and a small tester object. This resides in a seperate test directory. Both src and test are marked as source directory.

The code of the class itself is working. and I can run it from eclipse, but the test object fails to run from eclipse. Eclipse keeps saying "The type org.junit.Assert is not accessible" on the very first line "import static org.junit.Assert.*;". I cannot find out what to do.

I have put junit4 on the classpath (build path> add library> Junit> Junit4).  The test class is created by eclipse itself (new Junit testcase, junit4). From the command line I can compile the java file to a class file, but eclipse refuses to find junit.

Manual works OK:

```
javac -cp /path/to/org.junit_4.13.0.v20200204-1500.jar Addtester.java
```

I must have overseen an important detail, but right now I am out of ideas.

Thanks in advance, Ruud

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it. Otherwise, show what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, in the _Libraries_ tab.

Comment: howlger, I did have that file. Deleting it was sufficient. Can you explain why this caused all this trouble?

Comment: Having `module-info.java` means using [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) which requires a `requires ...;` line in that file and the JAR on the modulepath, not on the classpath (`-cp`).

Comment: Same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60447530/6505250