# "JavaPlugin is not accessible" error in eclipse when trying to import spigot api?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Before you mark this as a duplicate I have already searched through every single once I could find and none of the answers worked. This is my code in eclipse:

```
package me.[my mc uname].myplugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {

    }

}
```

Getting this error on line 3: `The type org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin is not accessible`

Yes i have the spigot api in my build path (spigot-1.15.2.jar)

I am running Java 64 bit 1.8.0, eclipse 64 bit 4.15, and windows 10 64 bit

- I have tried removing JavaPlugin and was getting the same error
- I have tried restarting my computer/eclipse/refreshing the script

I dont know what to do

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (or learn about [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)). Otherwise, what gives you Ctrl+1 in the line with the error?

Comment: It worked! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Great. For details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60447530/6505250

Comment: @howlger thanks!! you should make your comment become an answer ;) . i spent many times searching for this and your solution worked.

Comment: Well, in this case, I think it's a duplicate. But without knowing the reason it is difficult to find the solution since there are too many other "is not accessible" errors.